# Parse XML doc from url with ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am not very familiar with XML and am learning ruby as I go. The problem I am having is that the xml file I am using is formatted different than all the examples out there. I am attempting to us Nokogiri as it seems to be a popular was of doing this.

My XML file is from a url and looks like this

```
<guides of="XML" rtn="5" tot="10" cv="1" a="XPU_NextStep" id="0" " w="" q="" g="Echo" gr="HomeRec" gt="doc" js_q="" token="0:1QeU|5iG|557|1Y7p|4rE|">
  <r t="Orbelle Toddler Bed - Cappuccino" g="Echo" s="1" rk="1" pt="0" at="0" pr="0" ar="0">
   <a n="onsale" v="Yes"/>
   <a n="SKU" v="OTI041"/>
    <display>
      <thumb n="imageName" v="http://images/mgen/master:OTI041.jpg?is=400,400"/>
      <labels>
        <l n="salePrice" v="Sale Price: 69.98"/>
        <l n="catName" v="Toddler Beds"/>
        <l n="id" v="OTI041"/>
      </labels>
    </display>
  </r>
  <r t="The Orbelle Contemporary Solid Wood Toddler Bed - Cappuccino" g="XPU_NextStep" tm="bed, toddler, toddler bed, the orbelle contemporary solid wood toddler bed cappuccino, toddler beds" s="0.4688" rk="2" pt="873" at="0" pr="0" ar="0">
   <a n="availableDomain" v="ToddlerBeds,KidsFurnitureMart"/>
   <a n="deptName" v="Kids"/>
   <a n="onsale" v="Yes"/>
   <a n="SKU" v="OTI029"/>
   <a n="nicheCategory" v="Kids Beds,Standard Toddler Beds"/>
    <display>
     <thumb n="imageName" v="http://images/mgen/master:OTI029.jpg?is=400,400"/>
      <labels>
        <l n="salePrice" v="Sale Price: 59.98"/>
        <l n="catName" v="Toddler Beds"/>
      </labels>
    </display>
 </r>
```

I am trying to grab the v="OTI041" from  under each

Right now I am just able to open the file with-

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.somesite.com"))
```

Comment: checkout this sax parsing options, http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/ New OX ruby parser seems to be 5 times faster than Nokogiri, https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
doc.xpath('//r/a[@n="SKU"]/@v').each {|x| puts x.value }
```

Also, note that you have a syntax error in the first line, at `... id="0" " ...`